react-leaflet Popup onClose event not firing
My react-leaflet popup has an arrow icon to expand its information, which is handled via useState. When the popup is closed, I want the expanded state to reset to false instead of persisting as open. I am trying to add an onClose function to my Popup component but it doesn't appear to be firing at all. I could not find any documentation on onClose or any equivalent function.
const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
...
...
<Marker
  key={market.id}
  position={[market.geometry.y, market.geometry.x]}
>
  <Popup onClose={() => console.log("closed closed")}>
    <PopupData
      market={market}
      isExpanded={isExpanded}
      onToggleExpand={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}
    />
  </Popup>
</Marker>


If anyone else is trying to figure this out, this is what I learned:
Instead of onClose, react-leaflet's Popup component uses an event called popupclose, which needs to be used in a descendant of the MapContainer. So I created a MapEventHandler component:
function MapEventHandler({ onPopupClose }) {
  useMapEvents({
    popupclose: () => {
      onPopupClose();
    },
  });
  return null;
}

I placed it inside my MapContainer and passed it my handlePopupClose function:
<MapEventHandler onPopupClose={handlePopupClose} />
